# Drawing a servo loop with Circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits, tikz-circuit-lib

I would like to draw this with Circuitikz. I am having trouble adding the V_in sign and the left differential amplifier. I cannot invert the positive and negative output signs. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: A servo loop]

Comment: Please show the code you have so far. It is a lot easier to help you then.

Comment: You should just be able to say `noinv output down`, see https://texdoc.org/serve/circuitikz/0#subsubsection.4.19.2 (For `circuitikz`; judging from the shapes on the figure your are mixing `circuitikz` with the internal Ti*k*Z circuit lib, you should use one or another)  --- anyway, if you add the code for a simple example we will be able to help much more.

Comment: Already having some reputation you should know better, shouldn't you? Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 1):

You should really post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228); anyway, what you ask can be solved like this:

1. Use the `raised` voltage style and suppress the special treatment for the battery for the input voltage;
2. Use the provided keys (links to the manual [in the comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/622211/drawing-a-servo-loop-with-circuitikz#comment1553259_622211)) for the amplifier.

More details are in the code comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \ctikzset{voltage=raised}
    % you can't have a two-color battery in circuitikz
    \draw[color=blue] (0,0) -- (0,0.5)
        % you want the battery treated the same way as a passive
        % component (plus and minus farther away)
        to[battery, bipole/is voltage=false, invert, *-*, v^<=$V_{\mathrm{in}}$] ++(0,2)
        -- ++(0,0.5);
    % You can also change the symbol, but to flip position of + and - is easy
    \draw (4,1.5) node [fd op amp, noinv input up, noinv output down]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]